# Build failed with an exception - flutter

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk

When I try `flutter build apk` ,  I had these error.. anyone can help ?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file 'C:\appkeys\key.jks

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      13.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1